# How can I pass the index of an ng-option to the model as a value in angularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my code I have a select with code that currently looks like this:

```
data-ng-options="choice.id as choice.singular for choice in doseUnitChoices"
data-ng-model="choiceId"
```

originally `doseUnitChoices` used to look like this:

```
[
 {id:1, singular: 'string'},
 {id:2, singular: 'string2'},
 {id:3, singular: 'string3'}
]
```

But now it no longer has the `id` value any more so I need to pass the `index` of their position in the array instead of the `id` as `choice.id` to the `ng-model`

I rewrote my ng-option to this:

```
data-ng-options="choice as choice.singular for choice in doseUnitChoices track by $index"
```

but the `ng-model` appears to stay undefined. So is there anyway to get the model value to be the `index` of the choice within `doseUnitChoices`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
data-ng-options="index as choice.singular for (index,choice) in doseUnitChoices"
```

Comment: Excellent this works! Can you please explain to me whats going on and how this works? I don't see any examples like this in the angular docs?